# Maven Liquibase plugin executing previous changesets

Tags: maven, liquibase

I would like to be able to apply the latest changes to a liquibase controlled database via Maven. My POM contains:

```
<plugin>                                                                       
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>                                           
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>                            
            <version>3.3.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.23</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>                                                 
            <configuration>                                                            
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/database/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>   
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>                                 
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb</url>                            
                <username>${db.user}</username>                                              
                <password>${db.password}</password>
                <verbose>true</verbose>                                          
            </configuration>                                                           
            <executions>                                                               
                <execution>                                                            
                    <goals>                                                            
                        <goal>update</goal>                                            
                    </goals>
                </execution>                                                           
            </executions>                                                              
        </plugin>
```

and when I run `mvn liquibase:update` I get the following:

```
[INFO]     driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[INFO]     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
[INFO]     username: dbUser
[INFO]     password: *****
[INFO]     use empty password: false
[INFO]     properties file: null
[INFO]     properties file will override? false
[INFO]     prompt on non-local database? true
[INFO]     clear checksums? false
[INFO]     changeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/database/db-changelog-master.xml
[INFO]     context(s): null
[INFO]     label(s): null
[INFO]     number of changes to apply: 0
[INFO]     drop first? false
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
INFO 23/07/15 13:09: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 23/07/15 13:09: liquibase: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
SEVERE 23/07/15 13:09: liquibase: src/main/resources/config/database/db-changelog-master.xml: src/main/resources/config/database/changesets-001.xml::1000::gavin: Change S
et src/main/resources/config/database/changesets-001.xml::1000::gavin failed.  Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tc_configuration'
already exists
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tc_configuration' already exists
```

It appears that Liquibase is trying to re-run changesets that have already been executed.

Is there a way to run only the new changesets?

Comment: Just a guess: Did you run liquibase before your maven setup on the commandline? Liquibase uses the path of the file to identify a changeset and the path might be different now that you try to let it run from within maven...

Comment: in case this is the file names clash, you might have to fix your migrations with `logicalFilePath `.

Answer (score 4):

Liquibase keeps track of what has already been executed in its own tables. It will not look if the table tc_configuration exists, before deciding whether to run the sql statement that creates it. Instead, it will check in its own tables if a changeset wit a given id has been executed. So in your case, apparently, the tc_configuration table has been created outside of liquibase, or liquibase tables have been manipulated.

If you start with an empty database and only update it with liquibase:update, liquibase will always run only the newest changes, exactly once.

Comment: More details: If you can manually determine that all or some of the changesets have corresponding tables/etc. in the database, you can use the Liquibase changelogsync command to re-create the rows in the DATABASECHANGELOG table. It sounds like you have some changesets that have been deployed and some that haven't, so you would need to do something when you ran changelogsync so that liquibase only syncs changesets that have been deployed. You could do that 'manually' by commenting out the un-run changesets, or you could give the ones that have been run a label and use the label in the command.

Comment: @SteveDonie's comment should be the answer. `changelogsync` fixed the issue for me when I had to move my Jenkins build server and it messed up my old migration scripts.